# Using Metrics timer with DropWizard AKKA project

Tags: java, timer, metrics, dropwizard, graphite

I am trying to time a method in one of my Actors, upon reading various posts on the internet it looks like the @Timed annotation is only applicable to dropwizard resources. In order to time a plain java method, I need to manually time it. Is there a good example that shows how to achieve this? I was looking for a complete example that will give an idea of where the different classes be and what they be.